# How to calculate the difference of datetime field and now in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I have a datetime field in my database that contains the following information:

```
2012-05-03 17:34:01
```

I want to check the difference between the datetime field and now:

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

I am attempting to work out how many days have passed between now and the time written to the database field.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried Googling `date difference php` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is the answer :)

```
$now = new DateTime();
$date = new DateTime("2012-05-03 17:34:01");

echo $date->diff($now)->format("%d days, %h hours and %i minutes");
```

Comment: $date->diff($now)->format("%d days");

"%d" does not always give correct results, but "%R%a" gives accurate result.

Answer (score 6):

```
$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
```

Answer (score 4):

[**date_diff**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime("now");
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: Cooooool. The number sign is so important.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between now and datetime:

```
$delta = time() - strtotime('2023-03-22 13:43:59'); // in seconds
```